# Can I plug dust collector into NEMA 6-50?

Tags: electrical

I've searched what feels like the whole internet for an answer to this seeming easy question, but cannot find a definitive answer:

I'm looking to purchase a 220v dust collector ([Shop Fox W1666](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00064NPXO)) to run in conjunction with a 110v table saw in the garage.

In addition to a single 110v 20a circuit, there's an unused NEMA 6-50 outlet in the garage, and I thought it made sense to purchase a dust collector that could plug into the unused 220v outlet, giving it a dedicated circuit to avoid overloading the regular 20a circuit that already runs the table saw. However, from what I've read on other threads in this forum it looks like the 6-50 outlet may have too much overhead amperage for the 12a dust collector to run safely (the breaker won't trip if there's a problem).

Is this true, and is there any way I can easily convert the NEMA 6-50 into a useful outlet for lower amperage 220v machines like the dust collector, perhaps using something like [this adapter/breaker](http://www.homedepot.com/p/AC-WORKS-1-ft-50-Amp-3-Prong-6-50P-Welder-Plug-to-6-15-20-Outlet-with-20-Amp-Breaker-S650CB620/312641290)?

I appreciate any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Can you change the 50A circuit for the NEMA 6-50 over to a smaller circuit? (this should just be a breaker and receptacle swap + a bit of pigtailing)

Comment: Once again, breakers are used to protect wiring not devices. Your dust collector most likely has internal controls to keep it protected.  But let's face it, a dust collector is a simple continuous predictable load, not subject to varying demands.  A table saw however is a completely different kettle of fish. Push that 2" maple thru too fast and you'll either trip the breaker or the internal thermal overload of the motor.  (don't ask me how I know that!)

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the device you linked is just what you need to safely connect your dust collector to that outlet. My suspicion would be that it's Chinese junk that is not properly certified, except that it's sold by Home Depot! More than that, the manufacturer, [acworks.com](https://acworks.com/), seems to be an American company.

I'd say: go for it.

Comment: It also includes a 20A overcurrent protection built in. So the worry about the breaker not tripping isn't an issue.

Comment: @ratchetfreak If it didn’t, I wouldn’t have approved it.

Comment: I figured I should mention it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

That adaptor looks ideally suited to your task allowing you to connect loads like your dust collector with 6-20 0r 6-15 plugs.

It may be cheaper to instead downgrade to a 20A breaker at the supply end of the wire and fit a 6-20 socket,  but when you get an electric car you'll probably be glad to have the 50A outlet available.